# Css on a specific div

Tags: html, css

Im trying to display a docx in my web page. My current flow is: save the document as html, read the file and post it on the site. The issue is, it generates css with rules that affect the whole document. For example, it colors all the links to blue and messes up with the whole site. 
There is any way to tell a style tag to relate only to a specific div? Thank you very much

Comment: Please read up on how to properly ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Please try to provide some code or files, and also add what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a selector on the outer/wrapper div to the code to be generated.
For this you would have to specify one on the markup.

Example:

```
<div class="mycode">
   content, divs, classes, links, uls etc
</div>
```

Then select it on the CSS:

```
.mycode a {

}

.mycode p {

}
```

These combinators may be useful:

**Child selector**

```
div > p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**Adjacent simbiling selector**

```
div + p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**General simbling selector**

```
div ~ p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: The issue is, that it references other classes in the generated style tags. Im unable to provide an example, but you can save docx as html and see the content. Thank you very much

Comment: You will have to edit the generated styles for a matching selector, as I previously mentioned. There is no way to specify it otherwise

Comment: @HenriqueM. is right. Html5 has a new feature for that but it is not yet full supported. [see the docs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp)

Comment: This scoped things looks exactly like what i need

Comment: But sadly its not supported on chrome.

Comment: Hi. Do you know of any tool that can help me add the selectors? Doing it with the plain string is a mess

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to answer without knowing how the HTML code being generated looks. But in short you need to be able to target the specific div you want to alter in some way. Adding a specific class to all the divs being generated this way and only targeting the content contained within that class would do it.

Comment: Im unable to post the examples, but you can save a word document as html and see the response